# Host key verification failed. TASK ERROR: Failed to run vncproxy

Tags: proxmox

I have the problem that my Proxmox cluster always shows this error here "Host key verification failed. TASK ERROR: Failed to run vncproxy." when I try to connect via webinterface to a VM on another node, I can access the VMs on the server and when I change the node, I can only access the VMs on that node.sometimes I also get the error "Error 500: Timeout while waiting for port '5901' to get ready!"

That means I can only access the VMs (VNC) from any node on that node and not from any other node.

[First error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGu19.png)

[Second error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNBd1.png)

[Third error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma5TS.png)

So far, I have deleted the known_hosts and run the command    `/usr/bin/ssh -e none -o 'HostKeyAlias=%HOSTNAME%' root@%IP% /bin/true`    once.

Answer (score 0):

try to ssh between all your Proxmox server passwordless, it should resolved your issue